# How to deploy Vaadin to OpenShift?

Tags: java, openshift, vaadin

I keep getting this error when I push to the OpenShift (small gear) git repository:

```
 remote: [INFO] auto discovered modules [your.company.MyAppWidgetset]
 remote: [WARNING] Failed to retrieve com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler based on project POM
 remote: [INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler version 7.5.10
 remote: [ERROR] Dec 27, 2015 8:36:25 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
 remote: [ERROR] INFO: Created user preferences directory.
 remote: [INFO] Compiling module your.company.MyAppWidgetset
 Connection to vaadindemo-omio.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've been trying to deploy this Vaadin demo app:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application -DarchetypeVersion=7.5.10 -DgroupId=your.company -DartifactId=. -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=war
```

The most relevant results from my research were:

- this proposed solution in the [Vaadin forum](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/8541285/9222238) which had no effect to me;
- [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512143/deploying-vaadin-app-in-openshift) which describes a different issue than what I'm facing at the moment.

I've SSH'ed into the server and verified that my user owns all the directories inside **app-root** except for **app-root** itself which is owned by **root** but I don't have permission to change it.

Unfortunately I don't enough experience with neither Vaadin nor OpenShift to be able to proceed.

How to get rid of the Maven build errors?

**Edited:**

The command to deploy is actually a git push where **origin** is the repo in OpenShift as described in their [documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-getting-started.html#step2).

The complete [log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1V5Erc3XR77BC42SevPjb8mFMK5v_lT8YfepDqBBf39k/edit?usp=sharing) and [pom](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0CQl4M5gcKHWHJWRnItRGhBbUE/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: 1) What is the exact command you are running when you say *deploy* (is it a maven deploy, war, etc) ? 2) Can you share your complete pom and log?

Comment: I can see a few errors in your logfile. `WARNING: Could not lock User prefs.  Unix error code 2.` indicates that the maven/java process is unable to write files in your home directory, [see this similar question for a possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960451/java-system-preferences-under-different-users-in-linux). Not sure this is the fatal one, but I believe you should fix them one at a time and retry.